# Parameter Selection in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have two tables:

```
Table1: 
portfolio_num AssetCode Ltv
112             111       0.12
113             222       0.11
114             333       0.13
911             111       0.12
912             222       0.11
913             333       0.13
```

And another table

```
Table 2: 
P_First P_Second  
112       112
112       911  
113       113       
113       912
114       114
114       913
```

I want that when the user will click on the "portfolio_num" in my report , for example "112" he will get this output in a second report:

```
portfolio_num AssetCode Ltv
112             111       0.12
911             111       0.12
```

Now I build a procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Give_DetailsForLoan]
@PortfolioID INT
AS
BEGIN

Select * 
from dbo.Table1 where portfolio_num 
in(
select P_Second from dbo.Table2
where  P_First = @PortfolioID
)

END
```

This is the procedure I pasted to the shared data set.

When I run the proceure on sql server management studio:

```
exec [dbo].[Give_DetailsForLoan] 112
```

I do get what I want :

portfolio_num AssetCode Ltv
112             111       0.12
911             111       0.12

However, I the SSRS I only get

```
portfolio_num AssetCode Ltv
112             111       0.12
```

When clicking on the portfolio num in the first report.

I think the problem is by setting the correct filter.

Any suggestion why the ssrs give me diffrent results? 
Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure is wrong

Assume you input parameter value 112, your inner query will be executed like

```
select P_Second from dbo.Table2 where  P_First = 112
```

Which will give you a result set

```
112
911
```

Now the remaining query will be like

```
Select * from dbo.Table1 where portfolio_num in (112, 911)
```

So you get only one row.

To get the result you need, you need to do a join, something like:

```
select * 
from table_1 t1 join table_2 t2 on t1.portfolio_num = t2.p_First 
where t2.p_First = @portfolioID
```

Hope it helps